# dsget all domain users

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003

I try to get all the members of my domain - using

```
dsget group "CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=cms,DC=local" -members -expand
```

But it returns an empty result. How can this be? If I look up the `Domain Users` in the AD GUI and view its members, I get the full list without problems.

Why is the command not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just explained by the fact that the `member` attribute of `Domain Users` does not contain any user. This group looks like a dynamic group based on a query.